# sql query for join two tables of different databases that are in two Servers

Tags: sql

i have two tables tableA in databaseA on ServerA and tableB in databaseB on ServerB.
i just want to perform fullouter join to these tables based on common fieldname of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can create a linked server (in Management Studio, that's under Server Objects.)  Then you can use a four part name to join the tables:

```
select  *
from    localdb.dbo.localtable as t1
full outer join
        linkedserver.remotedb.dbo.remotetable as t2
on      t1.col1 = t2.col1
```

If you're using another database, please edit your question to say which.